# Upstart: stop on runlevel [016] vs stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, runlevel

So, I'm working on an upstart init script for mysql. Should be trivial, right? My stop stanza looks like:

```
kill timeout 30
stop on runlevel [016]
```

I `shutdown now -r`, and mysql yells about my MyISAM tables being crashed, just like I'd `kill -9`'d my mysql process. Boo. Upstart doesn't seem to be waiting for mysql to quit before restarting. Some searching on Google finds me [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36855/upstart-pre-stop-killed-during-shutdown) suggesting I do, instead:

```
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
```

and indeed, that seems to fix the problem.

But: WFT? Essentially, I want to make sure mysql is stopped before trying to unmount the local filesystems. Is this the right way to do this? Why is my `stop on runlevel` stanza not waiting for mysql to stop before switching runlevels?

And: is this y'know, documented anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue he is actually caused by Upstarts flexibility in handling both Upstart jobs and SystemV services on Ubuntu.

For information on events, a good place to look is the man pages on your system. If you're running Ubuntu Natty or newer, you'll now have upstart-events(7):

```
man 7 upstart-events
```

This gives you a lot of information. Here's an online version of (most of ) that man page:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific

Currently, the shutdown for an Ubuntu system is actually finalized by the SysV side of the work (for historical reasons). If you '`stop on runlevel [016]`', your job will *start* to stop when that `runlevel` event is emitted. However, if it takes too long, the **SystemV** part of the system (`/etc/init.d/*`) will actually take control and shut the system down. Whereas, if you '`stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]`', **Upstart** (not SystemV) will run your job and *once mysql has stopped*, then continue to start the SystemV shutdown sequence.

The Upstart Cookbook contains lots of examples like this:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/upstart_cookbook.pdf